# How to solve a non-linear equation using nleqslv package in R?

Tags: r, nonlinear-functions

I have this equation to solve (e.g. f(x,y) = 0):

```
library(nleqslv)
target <- function(x)
{
  z = x[1]/(x[1]+x[2])
  y = numeric(2)
  y[1] <- z*exp(-x[2]*(x[2]+z*(1-exp(-x[1]/z))))-0.00680
  y[2] <- z/x[2]*(1-exp(-x[2]))-exp(-x[2])*z/x[1]*(1-exp(-x[1]))-3.43164
  y
}

# Usage
xstart <- c(1,1)
target(xstart)
nleqslv(xstart, target, control=list(ftol=.0001, allowSingular=TRUE),jacobian=TRUE,method="Newton")
```

using R with nleqslv or another you have others :)

Thanks

Comment: What are the numbers -0.00680 and -3.43164 ? 
I'm getting error: 
Error in fn(par, ...) : argument "y" is missing, with no default...are you getting the same?

Comment: They are a part of equation :). I have an equation like this f(x,y) = (z*exp(-y*(y+z*(1-exp(-x/z)))) ; z/y*(1-exp(-y))-exp(-y)*z/x*(1-exp(-x))) = (a , b) where (a,b) can take some specified values. In the post, I put (a,b) = (0.00680 ; 3.43164).

Comment: The error is caused by a wrong definition of the function target ... the nleqslv use vectors ... I fixed the problem, now you can try and you will have another message :)

Comment: ok, thats a good observation... :)

Comment: In your function there is an error assigning to the vector `y`. `y[0]` does not exist in R and R ignores that completely. Indexing of vectors starts with index `1`. So you should use `y[1]` and `y[2]` instead. If you do that you get an ill-conditioned jacobian. If you run `nleqslv(xstart, target, control=list(btol=.01),jacobian=TRUE,method="Newton")` you will see that the first column of the jacobian is almost zero. Using `allowSingular=TRUE` in `control` doesn't help. So are you sure the function has been correctly specified?

Answer (score 1):

I have been experimenting with your function. Rewrite the `target` function to use the `a;b` constants in your comment as in your second comment as follows:

```
target <- function(x, a=.00680,b=3.43164)
{
  z <- x[1]/(x[1]+x[2])
  y <- numeric(2)
  y[1] <- z*exp(-x[2]*(x[2]+z*(1-exp(-x[1]/z))))-a
  y[2] <- z/x[2]*(1-exp(-x[2]))-exp(-x[2])*z/x[1]*(1-exp(-x[1]))-b
  y
}
```

The default values for `a` and `b` are what you initially specified.
Using them you'll get an ill-conditioned jacobiam.

However if we give some other values to `a` and `b` for example like so

```
nleqslv(xstart, target, control=list(btol=.01),jacobian=TRUE,method="Newton",a=2,b=1)
```

or

```
nleqslv(xstart, target, control=list(btol=.01),jacobian=TRUE,method="Newton",a=2,b=2)
```

then for the first expression the full return value of `nleqslv` is

```
$x
[1]  2.4024092 -0.7498464

$fvec
[1] 1.332268e-15 2.220446e-16

$termcd
[1] 1

$message
[1] "Function criterion near zero"

$scalex
[1] 1 1

$nfcnt
[1] 10

$njcnt
[1] 7

$iter
[1] 7

$jac
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.2930082 -1.2103174
[2,]  0.1801120 -0.6566861
```

I am inclined to conclude that either your function is incorrect or that you have specified impossible values for `a` and `b`. Method `Broyden` also seems to work nicely.

Comment: Your example work nicely !! Thanks :)  But I have no idea how to change my equation to get well specified problem :)

Comment: Is there any way to visualize this equation ?

Comment: See if you can find a 2D plot function in R. Changing the equation is up to you; I haven't got a clue.

Comment: Thank you Bhas for your help !