# solving non-linear equation with constraints in R

Tags: r, constraints, equation, solver

I need to convert an VBA script to R. There is solver involved and I do not know which package to choose or how to implement the following problem:

equations:

y=0.42*a+(1-0.42)*b

(y is a given value between 0 and 1)

4.65=(a/(1-a))/(b/(1-b))

variables: a, b

constraints:

0 < a < 1; 0 < b < 1

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Given the description you are trying to solve a system of equations consisting of 2 equation and 2 variables. So what value does `y` have? Or do you want to minimize/maximize `y` subject to a restriction? Please clarify.

Comment: Consider posting this question in Cross Validated. While this is related to VBA and R, it's more of a methods problem than a programming problem.

Comment: Bhas, thank you, I specified Y: it is a constant between 0 an 1 (which will vary per iteration)

Comment: Disagree with @JuanBosco - it is not at all a statistical problem to solve 2 equations with 2 unknowns. Cross validated would be inappropriate.

Comment: Searching for "solve nonlinear equation in R" mostly points to the [`nleqslv` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=nleqslv), I'd start there. [Here's an example on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38684295/903061).

Answer (score 0):

Construct a function `f` like this

```
f <- function(x,y) {
    z <- numeric(length(x))
    # x[1] is a
    # x[2] is b
    # y=0.42*a+(1-0.42)*b
    # 4.65=(a/(1-a))/(b/1-b))

    z[1] <- y - (.42*x[1]+(1-.42)*x[2])
    z[2] <- 4.65 - (x[1]/(1-x[1]))/(x[2]/(1-x[2]))
    z
}
```

To find a zero for `f` different values for y satisfying you restriction you could try something like this:

```
xstart <- c(.5,.5)

for( y in seq(.1,.9,.1) ) {
    res <- nleqslv(xstart,f,y=y)
    cat("*** y = ", y, "***\n")
    print(res)
}
```

And do not forget to test if a solution was found (see the documentation of package `nleqslv`). It appears that the solution satisfies your restriction.
You can't constrain the solution if you want to find a zero of the function. If it doesn't satisfy your restriction there is no solution.
If a solution does not satisfy your restrictions you could skip it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Bhas!

Finally I implemented like this

findValue= function(y){

```
xstart <- c(y,y)

res <- nleqslv(xstart,equations,y=y)

res = c(as.numeric(substr(res[1], 3, 11)),as.numeric(substr(res[1], 22,30)) 

return(res)
```

}

equations <- function(x,y) {

```
z <- numeric(length(x))

# x[1] is a

# x[2] is b

# y=0.42*a+(1-0.42)*b

# 4.65=(a/(1-a))/(b/(1-b))


z[1] <- y - (.42*x[1]+(1-.42)*x[2])

z[2] <- 4.65 - (x[1]/(1-x[1]))/(x[2]/(1-x[2]))

z
```

}

Comment: Please test `res$termcd` to see if a solution was found! See the documentation.