# Which function to choose and how to write when my objective function is min(x-y)^2 in R?

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I try to converting optimization problem from Excel to R, but sturggling with how to coding in R.

I solved this problem in Excel with non-linear solver. I would like to find the set of x  that provide sum of least diffence value from set of given value, y.  minimize (x-y)^2 and constraints are x >= A, x >= By. Because of the constraint limit in Excel, I am trying to write in R, but do not know how to set up the objective function.

```
Y <- C(10,40,10,20) 
find the X that give MIN sum of (X-Y)^2.
Subject to;
X_1 + X_3 >= 50
X_2 + X_4 >= 50
X_1 + X_2 >= 40
X_3 + X_4 >= 60
solve for all four X value.
```

Nonlinear Solver in Excel give the solution as X_1 = 15, X_2 =25 , X_3 = 35, X_4 = 25

Comment: You'd probably need the nleqslv package to solve this. You can find an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684295/how-to-solve-a-non-linear-equation-using-nleqslv-package-in-r

Comment: @Arno No, nleqslv is not for optimization